# How to force a Linux C Executable to access the disk for fetching data

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I am currently working on a project and I need to test its performance. Thus, I am developing a C client which accesses random disk pages from a file repeatedly. The client is targeted for a Linux Debian OS (64 bit) and operates as follows:

On the beginning, it allocates a dynamic in-memory structure which holds the information of the pages it will access. Then, during a number of rounds it fetches the data from the file for each page.

In order to monitor the underlying FileSystem performance, I want to force the client to replace RAM contents with new pages and not improving its performance with Caching. So, I make it use most of its RAM (it has 512MB of main memory and I force it to use ~ 300MB). The fact is that I do not monitor performance degradation.

Is there another way to force the replacement of memory pages in main memory, so I can monitor IO Delay in my clients' calls?

Comment: Do I get you right: you want to force the kernel to reload a page from file into RAM on each access instead of using potentially cached ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flush the memory cache by doing this (as root):

```
   sync
   echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

The various [values](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) `drop_caches` accepts are:

```
To free pagecache:
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
To free dentries and inodes:
    echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
To free pagecache, dentries and inodes:
    echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

You'll need 3 to drop everything.

Comment: Is it better to use 2, for just dropping fs related chaches, or is 3 required? [Ref](http://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches)

Comment: 2 only drops dentries and inodes, not the pagecache that'll hold actual file content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @nos. This have never occurred to me.